# what year was David born?

Tags: time, king-david

According to the Jewish calendar year, what year was king David born?

Comment: Seems off-topic as asking about Jewish individuals rather than Judaism.

Comment: Fascinating question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chabad.org [David the Shepherd](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/463958/jewish/David-the-Shepherd.htm) says

> David was born in Beth-Lehem, in the land of Judah, in the year 2854.
>   He was only ten generations removed from Judah, one of Jacob's twelve
>   sons.

An alternate way of counting is to consider the [building of the Bais Hamikdash](https://sabbahillel.blogspot.com/2015/05/rabbi-leibtag-shiurim-hebrew-calendar.html), and count back.

> The next block of time is from Yetziat Mitzrayim until the start of
>   construction of the first Beit HaMikdash, a period Sefer Melachim
>   informs us was 480 years (Melachim I 6:1). We can therefore establish
>   that the Beit HaMikdash began its time in year 2928 of Seder Olam.

Shlomo Hamelech therefore began his reign in 2924. David Hamelech lived 70 years, which makes his birth date 2924 - 70 = 2854. This confirms the date given by chabad.org.

Comment: thank you. i read that our year 5778 is (david's birth year+35) x2

Comment: @m.r. interesting so one can invent calculations based on mashiach coming when as many years pass from start of the reign of Shlomo or building of bais hamikdash as from creation to that time

Comment: David reigned over "all Israel" for 33 years, so multiply +37 by 2 for a nearby number.

Comment: i think the connection was Adam is Aleph-Dalet-Mem = Adam - David - Moshiach. so the half way point between the three is when David=35 years old.

Comment: which would be exactly half of our current year - 2854=5778/2

Comment: @m.r. So this says mashiach should come this year.

Comment: we can only know for sure when it happens

Answer (score 1):

http://www.beingjewish.com/mesorah/timeline.html
says
King David born
2854
(907 BCE)

Comment: The question is, from where does the author of this webpage retrieve his information?